# Oracle Connection exception via JDBC

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I have installed Oracle 11gR2 on my machine, now when i try to connect to it using IP address as 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' there is no issue, but when I use ip address of machine '192.168.1.6' it throws exception: Io exception: Then Network Adapter could not establish the connection.

I have installed ms loopback adapter prior to installation and my machine get IP from DHCP.
do i need to configure any setting oracle config or  what i might be missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Before looking at the network you need to check what address your listener is actually configured for. If it's specifying localhost or 127.0.0.1 then you won't be able to access remotely. If it's specifying a different IP previously allocated by DHCP then your current one won't work. If it's a host name, is that resolvable to your DHCP address?

As well as looking at listener.ora, you can try running `netstat -an | find "1521"` to see what address(es) it's actually listening on.

Answer (score 0):

It's a network issue. Likely a firewall, router or proxy somewhere in the line isn't properly configured to forward the desired port.

Not a programming problem.

Comment: will this be the issue even if i try to connect from same machine, just use the ip, instead of localhost?

Comment: When connecting to localhost you're basically connecting to the local host machine and not somewhere else in the network, so there can in fact be no networking problem, only maybe an extremely strict software based firewall which is installed at the local machine.

Answer (score 0):

localhost and 127.0.0.1 are known to be the local machine. It can bypass a lot of the fluff.

When you try for 192.168.1.6, it will go and 'ask' a router (or similar) to send the traffic to that IP address. First I'd try to PING the IP address. If that works, I'd try `telnet 10.253.82.33 1521` to see if you can connect to the port without involving JDBC or SQL or anything.